# How do I avoid fuzzy images on html emails?

Tags: html-email

When I export images from photoshop, particularly if they have text on, and I use them in an HTML marketing email, they appear fuzzy and unclear like the example below:

Fuzzy text in button

[image: Fuzzy text in button]

When I open the image as a png on it's own it looks fine, but when used inside an eshot and previewed in the browser it appears fuzzy.

Here's how i'm inserting the image in HTML:

```
<tr>
   <td width="210" align="center">

     <a href="link">
     <img style="display: block;margin: 0;padding: 0;" width="210" src="images/take-a-look-contemp.png">
     </a>

    </td>
</tr>
```

Here's how im exporting my image from photoshop:

Photoshop export specs
[image: Photoshop export specs]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The true width of the image is 1307px, so when you insert it as 210px, the browser has to scale it down, causing the bluriness--but only when scaled down.

[image: Image specs]

If you export it as 210px, it will be crisp, and 420px would work too (to cater for high-density pixel screens, such as retina screens on iPhones). 420px works because at 210px it's 50% size, which evidently is easy enough to scale. Everything else will blur.